# Default Omnicomplete support

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I just enabled omnicomplete function(I'm using Vim7.3) and I want to try it out so I wrote a test.c:

```
int main
{
   int appleInc;
   app_
}
```

"_"is where the current cursor is.But when I hit Ctrl X or Ctrl O, nothing pops up. It just say pattern not found.

I'm a bit confused by this. Doesn't it at least supposed to support the variable autocompletion? 
This is what I add in the .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

Comment: Mine is `omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete`

Comment: filetype indent plugin on ...
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete ...
set completeopt+=longest,menuone ...
then type something in insert mode ... followed by ctrl+x  ... ctrl+o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct shortcut for omnicompletion is `<C-x><C-o>` that's `<C-x>` *then* `<C-o>`.

In this case, you want `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` to complete with a keyword from the current buffer and other sources or `<C-x><C-n>`/`<C-x><C-p>` to complete with a keyword from the current buffer only.

See `:help ins-completion`.

Comment: Thx, so omnicomplete is mainly for like a language keywords? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Use it for builtin methods and such and use the other to save typing.